# Mongodb. Select elements from an array by $MAX and $EQ criteria

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

```
{
   "_id": 1,
   "values":[
      {
         "value1":10,
         "value2":12,
         "value3":30
      },
      {
         "value1":20,
         "value2":12,
         "value3":100
      },
      {
         "value1":30,
         "value2":14,
         "value3":50
      }
   ]
}
{
   "_id": 2,
   "values":[
      {
         "value1":10,
         "value2":12,
         "value3":60
      },
      {
         "value1":20,
         "value2":12,
         "value3":80
      },
      {
         "value1":30,
         "value2":14,
         "value3":70
      }
   ]
}
```

I would like to find the document where (for example):

```
values.value1 = 20
values.value2 = 12
values.value3 is max of all values.value3
```

I want to get one document that contains one element of the array. For example:

```
{
   "_id": 1,
   "values":[
      {
         "value1":20,
         "value2":12,
         "value3":100
      }
   ]
}
```

Or in sorted form. The document with the maximum value.value3 element must be the first and element of array with maximum value.value3 must be first. For example:

```
{
   "_id": 1,
   "values":[
     {
         "value1":20,
         "value2":12,
         "value3":100
      },
      {
         elements...
      }
   ]
}
{
   "_id": 2,
   "values":[
      {
         elements...
      }
   ]
}
```